# How to apply HMM for each class separately in R?

Tags: r, hidden-markov-model

I am using `depmixs4` package in R to apply HMM for a classification problem. My response variable is binary. I should train HMM for each class separately. I split the data set into two data sets one for each class.
y is a binary variable, and in the first split dataset, its value is  1.
I run the code below but it gives error

```
msp <- depmix(y~1,nstates=2,data=test)
set.seed(1)
fmsp <- fit(msp)
Error in em.depmix(object = object, maxit = emcontrol$maxit, tol = emcontrol$tol,  : 
  likelihood decreased on iteration 1
```

I would appreciate if anybody can tell me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Without the data, it is difficult to see what is the problem. You could try running the estimation with different random seeds. Do you always have this problem? `depmixS4` uses the EM algorithm by default, but you could also try to use a numerical optimizer:

```
fmsp <- fit(msp, method="rsolnp")
```

to see whether this works. But that the likelihood went down on the first iteration of EM makes me think that there could be issues in the data or model specification.